# How to select parent from inner element and apply styles to other inner elments of only this parent by .each()?

Tags: jquery

*Well, the question title was not easy to formulate. Maybe an editor can improve it?*

**Situation:** I have 4 tables with the same class name:

```
<table class="tb">
  <tr><td class="markit">1a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1c</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="tb">
  <tr><td>2a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2b</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="tb">
  <tr><td>3a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3b</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="tb">
  <tr><td class="markit">4a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4b</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want jquery to change the border color of **all cells below** `.markit` within the **same table**, which would be `<td>1b</td>` and `<td>1c</td>` and `<td>4b</td>`.

I tried:

```
$(".markit").each( function() {
  $('td:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')').css('border-left','4px solid #CCD');
});
```

But it is changing all **td**'s.

I need to tell jquery to only use the tds of the **current parent** but I don't know how to set up the selector.

Working code can be seen in this calendar "[Ferienkalendar](http://www.echteinfach.tv/ferien/)" see today's column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the prettiest code ever, but try this:

```
$("table .markit").parent('tr').nextAll().find('td').css('border-left', '4px solid #CCD');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pg4wa/)

This code finds all `.markit` elements, then finds the `td` elements of all sibling `tr` of the `markit` and add the styling to them. I would suggest making that styling a class and using `addClass` to make maintenance easier in the future. You can also use `addBack()` to include the original `.markit` element:

```
$("table .markit").parent('tr').nextAll().addBack().find('td').addClass('after-markit');
```

[**Example including original markit element**](http://jsfiddle.net/pg4wa/3/)

Comment: FYI, `andSelf` is deprecated as seen at the top of the [API page](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/#entry-longdesc) (still usable at the moment, but just an alias)

Comment: nextAll() and find() were new to me. Thanks for extending my jquery knowledge. Btw, I forgot to note that there are several TDs in one row. The solution would then be with each() and something like: `$('.markit').each( function() { $(this).parent('tr').nextAll().find('td:nth-child('+($(this).index()+2)+')').css('border-left', '4px solid #CCD'); });` PS: Yes, I am using addClass() now :)

Comment: To only target one column of cells, change the find to: `.find('td:eq(n)')` where `n` is the 0-based index of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
$(".markit").parent().parent().find('td').each(function() {
    $(this).not('.markit').css('border-left','4px solid #CCD');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/XAaDY/)

Comment: And here is a fiddle for that, slightly different ;) http://jsfiddle.net/8p5cK/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".markit").each( function(obj) {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('td').css('border-left','4px solid #CCD');
});
```